# How to select the lowest value from selection

Tags: mysql, database, select

I'm using MySQL 5.1

table users:

```
id | exp
---------
5  | 5
4  | 9
```

table levels:

```
id|min_exp
----------
1 | 0
2 | 5
3 | 8
```

How to select user with his levels.id?

I need to join table users and levels.
This must be valid:

```
users.exp >= levels.min_exp
```

and min_exp should be lowest as it can be.

expected output:

```
users.id|users.exp|levels.id|levels.min_exp
   5    |    5    |    2    |      5
   4    |    9    |    3    |      8
```

Comment: I'm not quite clear on what you are asking.  Can you edit your question and provide an example of the output you are expecting?

Comment: is there a level_id in your user table?

Comment: Provide information on which columns those tables should be joined because there is no column in `levels` table that could be used for join with `users`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there are no gaps in level.id, you could get better performance by joining `levels` twice and avoiding aggregates:

```
select users.id, users.exp, current_level.id, current_level.min_exp
from levels current_level
join levels next_level on next_level.id = current_level.id + 1
join users on users.exp >= current_level.min_exp
    and users.exp < next_level.min_exp
```

If you need the min/max experience bracket frequently, I'd recommend making the `current_level`/`next_level` join a view.

Edit:  It just occurred to me that this fails for users at maximum level.  Depending on how you want to handle that (do users stop gaining XP at max or continue gaining it without increasing level?), you could add a dummy record above max level in `levels` or make the `next_level` join an outer join.

Comment: This version has severe performance issues. It has to match all rows from both tables. Filtering it down to return just a single user's level still has to match all rows from the levels table.

Comment: @TupshinHarper:  Judging by the expected output, the query should get the level for all users.  I'll grant that using `order by` / `limit 1` or an aggregate performs better for querying a single user, but not for querying all users.  To perform the grouping and aggregation for all users, the DBMS would build an intermediate record set with `U * (1/2) L`, where U is the number of records in users and L is the number of records in level (assuming an even distribution of users by level).  The self-join on `level` allows the optimizer to use 2 record sets with sizes U and L to build the result.

Comment: Fair enough. Your answer is great for returning all users' levels, which does, indeed, look like what they are asking for. For the special case of returning a particular user's level, I'd still recommend my version below.

Answer (score 1):

You want the min level that the user can see:

```
select
    u.id as UserId,
    MIN(l.id) as LevelId
from
    Users u
    inner join Levels l on
        u.exp >= l.min_exp
group by
    u.Id
```

If you want it just for a specific user:

```
select
    u.id as UserId,
    MIN(l.id) as LevelId
from
    Users u
    inner join Levels l on
        u.exp >= l.min_exp
where
    u.id = 5
group by
    u.Id
```

Comment: I believe you want the *minimum* level whose "exp" requirement the user's experience surpasses, not the maximum.

Comment: Eric, I believe he wants the lowest experience level (ie, the current level for the user). The max(l.id) should be min(l.id)

Answer (score 1):

The question is phrased unclearly, but from the context, it looks like you are looking for the highest level that a person has achieved given their current exp and the min_exp.

Since you know the id of the user you are looking for, the query can be

```
select users.id as uid,users.exp,levels.id as levelid from users,levels where users.id = 4 and levels.min_exp <= users.exp order by levelid desc limit 1
```

if you make sure you have proper indexes on both tables

```
alter table users add primary key (id)
alter table levels add primary key (id)
alter table levels add unique key(min_exp);
```

(non primary key indexes would be fine too)
Then the query is extremely efficient:

```
explain select users.id as uid,users.exp,levels.id as levelid from users,levels where users.id = {{uid}} and levels.min_exp <= users.exp order by levelid desc limit 1;
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users  | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | const |    1 |                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | levels | index | min_exp       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL  |    1 |     Using where |
----+-------------+--------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+`
```

Comment: I can't comment on other responses yet, but the leading answer right now is proportional to *both* the size of the users table and the size of the levels table. If you modify it to just return the level of a single user (users.id), then it is still proportional to the size of the levels table (run explain on it).